# two consecutive code examples in kramdown/showoff

Tags: ruby, markdown

I use [showoff](https://github.com/schacon/showoff) with [kramdown](http://kramdown.rubyforge.org/index.html) for slides, but `@@@` doesn't work correctly.

```
# Example #

    @@@ xml
    <W C="VBN" id="W151" o1="758" o2="767">inhibited</W>

    @@@ prolog
    [inhibited]
```

This renders the `@@@ prolog` part as it would be yet another bit of
the same codeblock, like this:

```
<W C="VBN" id="W151" o1="758" o2="767">inhibited</W>

@@@ prolog
[inhibited]
```

I'd like it this way:

```
<W C="VBN" id="W151" o1="758" o2="767">inhibited</W>

[inhibited]
```

It doesn't generate a second `<pre><code>` tag for the `@@@ prolog` part, therefore showoff doesn't find it.

```
  html.css('pre').each do |pre|
    pre.css('code').each do |code|
      lines = out.split("\n")
      if lines.first.strip[0, 3] == '@@@'
        ...
```

Changing the source to

```
   @@@ xml
   <W C="VBN" id="W151" o1="758" o2="767">inhibited</W>

<pre><code>
@@@ prolog
[inhibited]
</code></pre>
```

doesn't activate the second highlighting. It works if I manually set the css classes, but that's a hack only.

Comment: Can you define "showoff" please?

Comment: I'm not convinced this is a programming question...

Comment: Where would you migrate it to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit of a hack but this seems to work for me:

```
# Example #

@@@ xml
<W C="VBN" id="W151" o1="758" o2="767">inhibited</W>

<pre/>
@@@ prolog
[inhibited]
```